# WPF AForge.net resize web cam image to custom size

Tags: c#, image, image-resizing, aforge

Hey all I am trying to figure out a way of customizing the size of the webcam image inside an image control.

Currently this is the code that draws the image:

```
private void video_NewFrame(object sender, Video.NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapImage bi;
            ResizeBicubic filter = new ResizeBicubic(400, 300);

            using (var bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
            {
                bi = bitmap.ToBitmapImage();
            }

            bi.Freeze(); // avoid cross thread operations and prevents leaks
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate { videoPlayer.Source = bi; }));
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error on _videoSource_NewFrame:\n" + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            StopCamera();
        }
    }
```

As you see I am trying to use **ResizeBicubic filter = new ResizeBicubic(400, 300);** to resize it but I can not seem to find anywhere to put the filter.Apply().

If I do something like this:

```
filter.Apply(bi);
```

It gives me the error of:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'

I also have code that finds the largest video res that particular web cam can do:

```
private void StartCamera()
    {
        if (CurrentDevice != null)
        {
            _videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(CurrentDevice.MonikerString);

            if (_videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length > 0)
            {
                string highestSolution = "0;0";

                //Search for the highest resolution
                for (int i = 0; i < _videoSource.VideoCapabilities.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (_videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width > Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[0]))
                        highestSolution = _videoSource.VideoCapabilities[i].FrameSize.Width.ToString() + ";" + i.ToString();
                }

                _videoSource.VideoResolution = _videoSource.VideoCapabilities[Convert.ToInt32(highestSolution.Split(';')[1])];

            }

            _videoSource.NewFrame += video_NewFrame;
            _videoSource.Start();
        }
    }
```

And that code does work to set the image to the largest size on the screen but like I said, I want to customize that size to whatever the actual image control is sized to.

Any help would be great!